# Adding a WKT specified coordinate system to ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, well-known-text

I've got a WKT specified coordinate system, how do I add this to ArcGIS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the file system, browse to the "Coordinate Systems" folder. This will be somewhere like C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Coordinate Systems depending on your version.

Place your file in the appropriate directory and it will be available in ArcCatalog and ArcMap in the same place.